# About Environment variable configuration of nestjs

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

in the file of app.module.ts, I used Environment variable

```
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: [`./src/config/${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`], isGlobal: true },),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.DATABASE_URL, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      user: `${process.env.DATABASE_USER}`,
      pass: `${process.env.DATABASE_PASSWD}`,
    }),
```

It was working when I test in local,But when I build it,The env is  not work,So what can I do ,Thinks

my package.json script

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=prod nest build", // the env not work
"start:dev": "NODE_ENV=dev nest start --watch",  // it works
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`build` and therefor `nest build` does not run the code, it runs the compiler to transform the `ts` files into `js` files, so there's never any check or evaluation of what `process.env.WHATEVER` is, it's just a translation from `ts` syntax (with all the types) to `js` syntax that can be interpreted by `node`.

`start:dev` (mapped to `nest start --watch`) is what is actually running the code, using `node` as the JavaScript engine.

You probably are wanting something like

```
"start:dev:prod": "NODE_ENV=prod nest start --watch"
```

Or you can modify the `start:prod` command Nest provides in new projects to be `NODE_ENV=prod node dist/main.js`

Comment: I think you meant `"start:prod"` instead of `"start:dev:prod"`.

Comment: No, I meant making a new script `start:dev:prod` to map to `NODE_ENV=prod nest start --watch` because Nest projects already have a `start:prod` like I mentioned in the second half of my answer. This new script would allow for hot reloading with the `prod` value for `NODE_ENV`